# Regex Match Item in List and Perform Action Based on Match

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, python-re

For the dataframe:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'values':['0','123','None','banana','this is a test','-nan']})
df1
```

I have written the following function to colour a cell value based on its contents:

```py
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import re

def color_missing_items(value):

  if re.match(r'^0$',value):
    color = 'green'
  elif re.match(r'^[1-9]\d*$',value):
    color = 'red'
  elif any(re.match(null_rep,value) for null_rep in nulls_list):
    color = 'grey'
  
  return 'background-color: %s' % color
```

The issue I am having is with the 2nd `elif`.

This is nulls_list:

```py
nulls_list=\
['','#N/A','#N/A N/A','#NA','-1.#IND','-1.#QNAN','-NaN','-nan','1.#IND','None','1.#QNAN','<NA>','N/A','NA','NULL','NaN','n/a','nan','null','Nan','NAN','NULL','na','--','-','__','_']
```

I want the cell to colour grey only if a value matches a value from nulls_list. Currently any string that doesn't match one of the other conditions still colours the cell grey regardless of whether the value is contained in nulls_list.

```py
df1.style.applymap(color_missing_items)
```

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @mmTmmR did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a different approach than a regex.

Try to convert to number, everything that fails will be grey:

```
def color_missing_items(s):
    s = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
    return 'background-color: ' + s.gt(0).mask(s.isna()).map({True: 'green', False: 'red', np.nan: 'grey'})

df1.style.apply(color_missing_items)
```

output:

[image: colored output]

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems:

1. Note that, the way you wrote your code, it will fail if neither of the branches of the if is true (since `color` will be undefined).
2. The first regex on your `nulls_list` is `''`. This matches everything. This is why you are not seeing the problem from item (1).

You should declare a default colour value and, since I'm assuming you want to make sure `nulls_list` matches a whole string, add a regex to match the beginning and the end of the string:

```py
nulls_list = [f'^{reg}$' for reg in nulls_list]   # Fix the regexes to match full string

def color_missing_items(value):

  color = 'blue'    # Ensure color is defined and give it a default value
  if re.match(r'^0$',value):
    color = 'green'
  elif re.match(r'^[1-9]\d*$',value):
    color = 'red'
  elif any(re.match(null_rep,value) for null_rep in nulls_list):
    color = 'grey'
  
  return 'background-color: %s' % color
```